# how to set space between 2 pivot items in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am trying to avoid space between 2 pivot items but not able to solve .If anybody knows how to set minimum space between swiping one item to next or vice versa then tell me, When user swipes it is displaying first image to next image or preview image but here there is some bug i.s. when user swipes one image then it displays one item gap between 2 pivot items and after that followed by next pivot items. How to resolve this?

Comment: Siddhu can u post ur xaml code?

Comment: <phone:Pivot x:Name="listbox" Grid.RowSpan="1"> <phone:Pivot.ItemTemplate><DataTemplate><Image Source="{Binding}"/>

Answer (score 0):

this can be easily achieve

```
<phone:Pivot x:Name="listbox" Margin="-24" Padding="0" Grid.RowSpan="1"> <phone:Pivot.ItemTemplate><DataTemplate><Image Source="{Binding}"/>
```

try it

Comment: I have try it but still same problem.

Comment: If i try to set margin it display image full size(To hide title bar,Header bar),i.s. "margin" attribute does not work for when user swipes one image then it displays one item gap between 2 pivot items and after that followed by next pivot items.

Comment: It display one pivot item space between swiping items.But i have need to swipe pivot items like windows phone media library(Photo swipe one by one without much space between  two items.)

Comment: when user swipes one image then it displays one item gap between 2 pivot items and after that followed by next pivot items. How to resolve this?

Comment: I am trying to avoid space between 2 pivot items but not able to solve,Some reason i am not sending screenshot